# How can I get nearest dates to year end in dataframe column?

Tags: python, date

I have a dataframe column from 1995 to today and I would like to create a boolean array that has True for the nearest date BEFORE the next year starts.

So for

```
["2000-12-22","2000-12-26","2000-12-29","2001-01-02"]
```

I expect:

```
[False, False, True, False]
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you convert them to `datetime`, sort them in increasing order and take the one with the highest day of the year?

Comment: How can I take the one with the highest day of the year?

Comment: See my answer..

Comment: When you say `dataframe` do you mean in pandas? Because what you write in your Q is a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin datetime library, https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html, to achieve this without external dependencies like pandas, numpy etc.

```
from datetime import date
```

Convert the supplied list of date strings, assumed to be in `isoformat`, to `datetime` objects:

```
list_of_date_strings = ["2000-12-22","2000-12-26","2000-12-29","2001-01-02"]
datetime_list = [date.fromisoformat(d) for d in list_of_date_strings]
```

Now convert to day of year:

```
datetime_years_of_day = [d.timetuple().tm_yday for d in datetime_list]
```

and create the mask:

```
mask = [d == max(datetime_days_of_year) for d in datetime_days_of_year]

print(mask) # -> [False, False, True, False]
```

In one go:

```py
    from datetime import date
    list_of_date_strings = ["2000-12-22","2000-12-26","2000-12-29","2001-01-02"]
    datetime_list = [date.fromisoformat(d) for d in list_of_date_strings]
    datetime_days_of_year = [d.timetuple().tm_yday for d in datetime_list]
    mask = [d == max(datetime_days_of_year) for d in datetime_days_of_year]
    print(mask) # -> [False, False, True, False]
```

Hey presto!

!TIP: No need to sort in fact. But if you want the one with the highest day in the year as per your comment just do

```
index_at_max = datetime_days_of_year.index(max(datetime_days_of_year))
max_in_date_string_list = list_of_date_strings[index_at_max]
```

There is a neater way to do this using sort plus a lambda and taking the last one in the list, so the method above is a bit more pedestrian but works at least.

Comment: Do I need to build a for loop? Because I will just get 1 date out , but as indicated in the question I should get 26 dates, so for each year (1995 to 2021). How can I achieve that?

Comment: This is not in your question that I can see? Is it homework.? Ah - yes you can of course loop over your dates, one per year

Answer (score 0):

`groupby` by year then `tail` to get latest in each year, then us `.isin` to check if given date is latest for given year

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":["2000-12-22","2000-12-26","2000-12-29","2001-01-02"]})
df["year"] = df["date"].str.extract("(\d\d\d\d)")
latests = df.groupby("year").tail(1)["date"]
df["islast"] = df["date"].isin(latests)
print(df)
```

output

```
         date  year  islast
0  2000-12-22  2000   False
1  2000-12-26  2000   False
2  2000-12-29  2000    True
3  2001-01-02  2001    True
```

Disclaimer: this solution assumes dates are already sorted in ascending manner.